# PHP/SQL simple search engine

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables: **companies, cities, categories and subcategories**. Here goes the structure of each of them:
**companies:**

```
company_name (varchar) NOT NULL
company_city_id (int) FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL
company_category_id (int) FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL
company_subcategory_id (int) FOREIGN KEY
company_description (varchar)
```

**cities:**

```
city_name (varchar)
city_id (int)
```

**categories:**

```
category_name (varchar)
category_id (varchar)
```

**subcategories:**

```
subcategory_name (varchar)
subcategory_id (varchar)
```

Now, according to this, I want to perform a search in the **companies** table using some search term. I need to show the companies that the searched words match or partially match the values existing on: **company_name, category_name, subcategory_name or company_description** in selected city and order the results according to relevance. The companies that match more the search terms on top. For example, I've been trying with this:

```
$city = 1;
$search_term = "pizza company";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies comp, categories cat, subcategories sub WHERE comp.company_city_id = :city AND
comp.company_name OR cat.category_name OR sub.subcategory_name OR comp.company_description LIKE '%:search_term%'";
$query = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array
(
    'city' => $city,
    'search_term' => $search_term
));
```

But this does not seem to be working very well. I have several repeated results, and if I reverse the word order the results do not appear. It seems that when I search for the category name there is no effect either. What should I do to get the result I expect?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: It shouldn't work. You have no placeholders. You are injecting the raw variable onto the query

Comment: You cannot combine `OR` clauses like that.  You must specify the condition for each of them (yes, a bit tedious, but such is life)

Comment: I use placeholders and PDO. I wrote the example code with hurry, I updated it.

Comment: @PatrickQ Ok, I tried that, but I'm still getting repeated results and results that does not match the searh terms. :/

Answer (score 1):

consider this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies comp, categories cat, subcategories sub WHERE 
comp.company_city_id = {$city} AND
comp.company_name LIKE '%{$search_term}%' OR cat.category_name LIKE '%
{$search_term}%' OR sub.subcategory_name LIKE '%{$search_term}%' OR 
comp.company_description LIKE '%{$search_term}%'";
```

Comment: This is not working, I'm still getting repeated results and results that does not match the search terms.